# How to use a cache in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

It used to be so simple in Laravel 3. `Cache::put($key, $data, $minutes);` - that's all!
Now I'm looking at the Laravel 4 source code, trying to figure things out, but it's too complicated for me. I would like to use the FileSystem cache.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same way pretty much.

[Laravel 4 Cache Docs](https://github.com/laravel/docs/blob/master/cache.md)

Comment: Ah, I see the problem was using it inside a class / file with a namescape, cause it says 'Class MyNS\Cache not found'. How can I use it there?

Comment: Since you're in a Namespace you need to call the Cache class from the root Namespace: `\Cache::put($key, $value, $minutes);` Or add: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;` to the top of your PHP file and 'Cache::put($key, $value, $minutes);`